# How to set keybindings systemwide?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, tty, keyboard-layout, bspwm

I am using bspwm in Arch Linux, without any Desktop Environment. I have swapped the escape and Capslock key for VIM, but the thing is, the keys only work in bspwm, i.e, if I change the tty then, the keys work as it never changed. I used
`setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **loadkeys** to change your keys in console with root access. Or use sudo.

For example:

I have Home key on my home row. I have bound it to Esc key. Here is my $HOME/.loadkeysrc

```bash
Keycode 102 = Escape
```

How do I load this key rc in TTY? Well, it depends on your shell. I use zsh so I have those lines in my **$HOME/.zprofile**

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
  exec startx -- vt1 -keeptty &>/dev/null
  logout
elif [[ $(tty) != /dev/tty1 ]]; then
  sudo loadkeys $HOME/.loadkeysrc
  tmux has-session -t $USER || tmux new-session -t $USER && tmux attach-session -t $USER
fi
```

So whenever I login to my system, and if it's first console, it will start an X session. Else, it will load my custom keys file and start/attack tmux session.

Comment: Can you be more specific? E.g., show an example command? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.